# IOException Upload to Artifactory from Jenkins Slave

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

Trying to upload artifacts to Artifactory from a Slave agent but getting the following exception.

```
Jenkins Artifactory Plugin version: 2.9.1
For pattern: Installer-(*).exe 1 artifacts were found.
Deploying artifact: https://*********/artifactory/****/0.0.0.0.zip
ERROR: remote file operation failed: d:\j\workspace\Test at hudson.remoting.Channel@ab91c59:JNLP4-connect connection from 2.38.60.62/2.38.60.62:59447: java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 502
java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed: d:\j\workspace\Test at hudson.remoting.Channel@ab91c59:JNLP4-connect connection from 2.38.60.62/2.38.60.62:59447: java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 502
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:992)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:974)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer.deploy(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:76)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.ArtifactoryGenericConfigurator$1.tearDown(ArtifactoryGenericConfigurator.java:392)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:174)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 502
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.uploadFile(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:565)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:278)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.deploy(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:217)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.invoke(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:189)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.invoke(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:130)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2731)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:94)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at ......remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from 2.38.60.62/2.38.60.62:59447(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1537)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:253)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:822)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:985)
    ... 9 more
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
Finished: FAILURE`
```

I have turned off Agent->Master Access Control, opened up all ports in firewall but still getting the same error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's what I did.
I configured the job again to upload from master and it failed.  However, it provided me the correct exception.  The reason was that the user account I was using didn't have write access to that repo.

Once I added required permissions, I was able to upload from slave.